# Using optional variables in query

Tags: linq, f#

I have a search type which is used to query the database as follows,

```
type UserSearch = 
  { limit: int option
    skip: int option }
```

I'm using `SQLProvider` and would like to use `limit` and `skip` variables in my query such as

```
query {
  for user in Db.getDataContext().MyDb.Users do
  select user

  // if searchParams.limit.IsSome then
  //     take searchParams.limit.Value
  // if searchParams.skip.IsSome then
  //     skip searchParams.skip.Value
}
```

Is it possible?

My current approach is as follows;

```
let mutable search =
  query {
    for user in Db.getDataContext().MyDb.Users do
    select user
  }

if searchParams.limit.IsSome then
  search <-
    query {
      for user in search do
      select user
      take searchParams.limit.Value
    }

search |> Seq.toArray
```

Since queries are lazy, this should result a single query, am i correct on this assumption?

Comment: You should return `IQueryable` from `search`, i.e. return `Db.getDataContext().MyDb.Users` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `query` builder turns the result into `seq<_>` and forces it to run the SQL query, so you cannot easily compose queries this way. There may be more sophisticated tricks you could use, but for your specific case, it may be easier to just use a reasonable default value such as `0` for `skip` and `Int32.MaxValue` for `take`:

```
query {
  for user in Db.getDataContext().MyDb.Users do
  skip (defaultArg searchParams.skip 0)
  take (defaultArg searchParams.limit.Value Int32.MaxValue)
  select user }
```

This will generate a query with `skip` and `take` even when you do not need that, which may have some performance implications - I do not think it matters, but it may be best to test that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. ` so you cannot easily compose queries this way.` does this mean my approach is problematic? if so, can you elaborate the problem?

Comment: @sardok The problem is that the result of `query { .. }` is `seq<_>` and so the query gets evaluated at the end of the block. If you do more operations on the result, it is done in-memory.